# PHPUnit @expectedException does not respect namesapce imports

Tags: phpunit

I found that PHPUnit's annotation `@expectedException` does not want to read class namespace paths from `use` statements (I'm using psr-0 for autoloading).

Take this as an example:

```
<?php

namespace Outrace\Battleship\Tests;

use Outrace\Battleship\Collection\MastCollection;
use Outrace\Battleship\Exception\CollectionOverflowException;

class MastCollectionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @expectedException CollectionOverflowException
     */
    public function testAcceptOnlyMasts()
    {

        $notMastObject = new \stdClass();
        $mastCollection = new MastCollection();
        $mastCollection->attach($notMastObject);
    }
}
```

The test, when run, will result in this error:

> ReflectionException: Class CollectionOverflowException does not exist

To remedy the situation, I tried adding `autoload-dev` to my compose.json and dumping autoload file again:

```
"autoload-dev": {
  "classmap": [
    "src/Outrace/Battleship/Exception/"
  ]
},
```

or with psr-4:

```
"autoload-dev": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Outrace\\Battleship\\Tests\\": "src/Outrace/Battleship/Tests/",
    "Outrace\\Battleship\\Exception\\": "src/Outrace/Battleship/Exception/"
  }
},
```

None of the above would solve the problem, the error would persist.

However, the test would work well if the annotation references a fullu qualified name of the exception class:

```
/**
 * @expectedException Outrace\Battleship\Exception\CollectionOverflowException
 */
public function testAcceptOnlyMasts()
```

Is this a limitation of PHPUnit or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation with how phpunit works.

Internally it uses php's [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) which expects the FQCN of the exception. It just takes the string you give it in the annotation.

TestCase.php has the following when checking exceptions `$reflector = new ReflectionClass($this->expectedException);` and the `expectedException` property is populated either from the annotation or a call to `setExpectedException()`.

You can use simplified names if you use the `setExpectedException()` method as you could then do something such as

```php
<?php
namespace Outrace\Battleship\Tests;

use Outrace\Battleship\Collection\MastCollection;
use Outrace\Battleship\Exception\CollectionOverflowException;

class MastCollectionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testAcceptOnlyMasts()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException(CollectionOverflowException::class);
        $notMastObject = new \stdClass();
        $mastCollection = new MastCollection();
        $mastCollection->attach($notMastObject);
    }
}
```